# how to add custom options that gets invoked after the application is installed using install4j?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to have a custom option after the application is installed using install4j. something like a custom application with screens and actions that needs to be invoked directly by the user by clicking on it after installation of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are called "installer applications" in install4j. On the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step, click on the add button, then select "Add application" and choose "Empty custom application" from the application templates.

You can invoke such applications via the API by calling

```
com.install4j.api.launcher.ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication(
  "<id>", null, false, null
);
```

See https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/launcher/ApplicationLauncher.html for the Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am able to create the custom application   how do i invoke it?

Comment: can custom installer application be directly invoked by user other than calling the API?

Comment: Yes, you can configure the "Executable name" property and the "Executable directory" property of the custom installer application.

Comment: yes I have already found that option where I can configure the executable directory.It works!Thanks again for your reply.